# What happens if docker container requires kernel features not provided by host?

Tags: docker

Can issues result if a docker image requires a kernel feature not provided by host OS kernel (e.g an image which requires a very specific kernel version)? Is this issue guaranteed to be prevented in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can issues result if a docker image requires a kernel feature not provided by host OS kernel

Yes, but note that the docker installation page recommend a minimun kernel level for docker itself to run.
[For instance on RedHat](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/installation/rhel/) "your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum".

If the image you run requires more recent kernel features, it won't work even though docker itself will.

> Is this issue guaranteed to be prevented in some way?

Not really, as illustrated in "[Docker - the pain of finding the right distribution+kernel+hardware combination](https://www.andreas-jung.com/contents/docker-the-pain-of-finding-the-right-distribution-kernel-hardware) "

As noted in "[Can a docker image based on Ubuntu run in Redhat?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122104/6309)"

> Most Linux kernel variants are sufficiently similar that applications will not notice. However if the code relies on something specific in the kernel that is not there, Docker can't help you.

Plus:

> system architecture is a limitation.
> x86_64 images won't run on ARM for exemple. I.E. you won't run the official ubuntu image on a Raspberry PI.